# Ubuntu 16.04 kernels >=4.4.0.143 break compatibility with VMWare 12

Tags: 16.04, kernel, vmware

I have had problems before, and after the kernel update to 4.4.0-143-generic #169 VMWare 12.5.9 is unable to start, services are incompatible and fail to start. Today I receive the new kernel 4.4.0.145-generic #153 and the problems continues.
I'm stuck in kernel 4.4.0-142-generic #168, and my VMWare 12.5.9 build-7535481, is working fine as always!
Anyone having the same trouble?
Any suggestion, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I have found so far for Ubuntu 16.04

1. upgrade to a more recent version of [vmware](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html)
2. if you need to stick to version 12 [instructions on how to edit the source code of
   the vmware modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126721/4-4-0-143-generic-upgrade-16-04-vmware-no-loger-working)

Background: the get_user_pages function has been changed to having one parameter less. Therefore the vmware-modules (vmmon,vmnet) can't compile. 
The actual vmware workstation version is 15 - which works fine (Mostly. I can't use it due to a hardware problem, I'm stuck with version 12)